# Hidden div to show where click

Tags: jquery, css

I need to have a hidden div and show it where ever I click on a page. Do I make its position relative? How do i associate with a position of a click?

Comment: Are you saying you want a div to show at the point on the screen where your user clicks?

Comment: Yes. Not precisely the pixel position, but rather several links that I will have on my page. The div would have to be positioned above the clicked link.

Comment: so there's one div that would need to appear above any link the user clicks? Or there are different divs, the relevant one of which would need to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know jQuery, then you can do a simple `css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY})` in replacement for this sample (click anywhere and you'll get the position):

http://jsbin.com/ufovo3

Here's the code:
http://jsbin.com/ufovo3/edit

```
$(document).click(function(e){ //Change the "document" to whatever you want
  alert('x: '+e.pageX+', y:'+e.pageY);
});
```

Here's a better demo:
http://jsbin.com/ufovo3/2/

source
http://jsbin.com/ufovo3/2/edit

Click it and watch it move where you click.

Answer (score 1):

get the position of your cursor using javascript: http://dev-notes.com/code.php?q=33

and set that as the left and top css position using position absolute :)

Comment: if you want to set it above the cursor just remove the div's height from the position :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the mouseX and mouseY propierties of an event.

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/
http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/

Then set the absolute position of the div after a click.

Comment: dude, he didn't mention jquery :).

Comment: @SnippetSpace The question is tagged jquery, isn't it?

Comment: That's it. It's tagged jquery :(

Comment: FYI, upvoted you because you obv. got down voted just because they missed the jQuery tag

Answer (score 1):

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/u7VfQ/)

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var height = $('#popup').height();
    var width = $('#popup').width();
    leftV = e.pageX - (width / 2) + "px";
    topV = e.pageY - (height / 2) + "px";
    $('#popup').css({
        left: leftV,
        top: topV
    }).toggle();
});


.popup{
    position:absolute;
    background:#cf5;
    z-index:10;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#4e4e4e;
    display:none;
}
```